# how to get additional debug after Job Failed (facebook-nodejs-business-sdk)

Tags: node.js, facebook

I'm unable to get the insights from the ad report from fb.

```
//npm install facebook-nodejs-business-sdk@3.2.12
const adsSdk = require('facebook-nodejs-business-sdk');
const AdsInsights = adsSdk.AdsInsights;
const account = new AdAccount(accountId);

let deprecatedFields = ["call_to_action_clicks", "cost_per_total_action", "social_clicks", "social_impressions", "social_reach", "total_actions", "total_unique_actions", "unique_social_clicks"]

let accountFields = [];
    for (let key in AdsInsights.Fields) {
        if (AdsInsights.Fields.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (!(deprecatedFields.indexOf(AdsInsights.Fields[key]) > -1)){
              accountFields.push(AdsInsights.Fields[key]);
            }
        }
    }

let insightReport = await account.getInsightsAsync(
        AdsInsights.Fields, 
        {
        time_range: timeRange,
          fields: `${accountFields.join(',')}`,
          limit: 10, 
          level: 'adset', 
            breakdowns: ['publisher_platform', 'platform_position', 'device_platform'],
            time_increment: 1,
        }
    );

 console.log("campaign report id", insightReport['report_run_id']) 
//################
```

With the report run id, I'm getting 'job failed' but I don't have any additional debug to figure out why or how it failed.

```
 $ curl --header "Authorization: Bearer (accesstoken)" https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/################
```

Result: 
`{"id":"################","account_id":"########","time_ref":########,"async_status":"Job Failed","async_percent_completion":0,"date_start":"2019-04-15","date_stop":"2019-04-16"}%`